# Are folder Id's unique in outlook web app folders?

Tags: outlook-web-app, outlook-restapi

I am using the outlook web app and have many folders in inbox, when I connect using the outlook api, I see that some folders have duplicate Id's.

As far as I know the folder Id should be unique for every folder, is that correct? There is no way of duplicating a folder in the web app, so what could be the reason behind duplicate folder Id's.

Answer (score 0):

Folders cannot have duplicate IDs. Can you show the REST response that contains duplicate IDs?

Comment: My mistake. They are not the same.There was a search caps issue with my code. Thanks